# SQLite3 helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Is there any application like SQL Buddy for SQLite3 for Mac. I am just starting with Ruby on Rails and have my environment set up on my Mac running Snow Leopard, I have used SQL Buddy before and I was wondering if anyone knows anything like that for SQLite3.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403/is-there-a-good-ide-for-sqlite

Comment: SQL Buddy has some support for SQLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this [Firefox Plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817).

Answer (score 0):

I use [base](http://menial.co.uk/software/base/) on OS X. It costs £10.00 but it is easy to use and had a great interface.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) runs on OS-X, though it's a bit flaky.

Honestly the command line sqlite3 app is pretty solid for what it is (e.g. you can import/export to CSV). Type `.help` from the prompt for commands.

Answer (score 0):

I also use Firefox SQLite Manager, or you can use the ruby  GUI for SQLite available out there.

Answer (score 0):

I use SQLiteManager. It's useful for importing/exporting data too. http://www.sqlabs.net/

Answer (score 0):

MesaSQLite is free and works well on OSX.